# Is it possible to post a variable from a view into a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to post a variable from a view into a controller?
I would like to set a variable in a view. i thought i need to do something like this to make it work -> example:

```
$test = '123';
```

And get it in the controller something like this:

```
$testing = $this->input->get($test, TRUE);
```

So i can use the $testing in a model.

fullcalendar.js:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
$( "#dialogstatusevent" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape:true, 
    resizable:false, 
    show:'fade',
    buttons: { 
      "Edit": function() {
      var 
      id = $("#idstatus").val(),


      if(startdatestatus=='' || enddatestatus=='')
            {
                //alert("Please do not empty....!",title="Hello");
                $("#d2").dialog("open");
                $("#d2").dialog({
                    buttons:{
                        "OK":function(){
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                $("#id:first").focus(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                exit;
            }//End if statement


     $.post('../testcalendar/db/processupdate.php',{
            id: id, action:'joined'
        }); var nTime = 1 * 50;
                window.setTimeout("location.reload()", nTime);
        $("#idstatus").val('');
        $(this).dialog("close");
        }, 
        "Cancel": function() { 
        $("#idstatus").val('');
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 

    }
    }

    );
    $("#idstatus").val(calEvent.idEvent),
        },
```

html for the id: 
    
            Id:

Controller i want to set the $test with the same id as the idstatus.:

```
$data['teamleden'] = $this->agenda_model->teamleden($test);
```

Model:

```
 function teamleden($test)
 {
  $this->db->select('evenementontvanger.idWerknemer, Werknemer.Voornaam,Werknemer.Achternaam');
  $this->db->from('evenementontvanger');
  $this->db->join('Werknemer', 'Werknemer.idWerknemer = evenementontvanger.idWerknemer');   
  $this->db->where('evenementontvanger.idEvent', $test);

  $query = $this->db->get();

   if($query -> num_rows()>=1)
   {
     return $query->result();
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: You can use sessions :)

Comment: Thats not quite what im looking for. I would like to request multiple times in the same session. Isnt there another way?

Comment: session arrays? `$_SESSION['test'][] = 123`, each time it will add new key to $_SESSION['test']. Also, why would you want to assign vars from view to controller at first place? At least you can declare it in the controller (not aware of the CI convention, but..) `$this->view->myVar = ''`; In the view `$this->myVar = 123`, so after a request, in the controller you will have `$this->view->myVar` with the value of `123`

Comment: you can pass values from view to controller and then controller to model

Comment: But how monu? I've edited my question with some code. hope it explains my question better.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/